# Share multiple node on openshift origin inventory

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to configure my inventory so I can install a 3 Master, 3 etcd, 1 compute and 1 infra node.
The thing is that I trying to do it all in 3 servers. So the need to share them.

I also have a 4 server that I'm using as LB.

This is the host file:

```
[masters]
server1
server2
server3

[etcd]
server1
server2
server3

[nodes]
server1 openshift_node_group_name="node-config-master"
server2 openshift_node_group_name="node-config-all-in-one"
server3 openshift_node_group_name="node-config-master-infra"

[lb]
server4

[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd
lb

[OSEv3:vars]
ansible_user=dxcooper
ansible_become=yes

openshift_deployment_type=origin
openshift_release="3.11"
openshift_master_default_subdomain=apps.<subdomains>
openshift_master_cluster_hostname=server4
openshift_disable_check=docker_storage

debug_level=2

openshift_http_proxy=http://<proxy>
openshift_https_proxy=http://<proxy>
openshift_no_proxy='localhost,127.0.0.0,127.0.0.1,127.0.1.1,local.home,.svc,.local,10.87.32.0/19,.<subdomains>'
```

The prerequisites.yml runs without problem.
When I run the deploy_cluster.yml, during the etcd installation it fails during the certificate creation part.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Hi there! What error do you got?  Also, and only for not assuming the answer, your VM CIDR is 10.87.32.0/19?

Comment: It was a proxy problem.  The openshift_no_proxy needs to have the IP as well as the FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking around and I saw several people with the same problem as well as bug in redhat.

For me it was a proxy problem.
The openshift_no_proxy needs to have the IP as well as the FQDN.